# How to get result of Get-WmiObject into a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, get-wmiobject

I have a PowerShell-V2 script I am trying to run. Very simply, I pass it an application, and it outputs the result of the win32_process.
e.g.

```
$filter = "name like '%"+$_Application+"%'"
$result = Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "$filter"
```

However I need to get this into a file.
But when I run:

```
write-host $result
```

I just seem to get the "__RELPATH" result, and not the whole thing.

Trying to get it into a file results in the same thing. Is there a way of doing this, without me having to loop through one by one, listing each one in turn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Out-File` cmdlet:

```
$result | Out-File 'your_file_path.txt'
```

**Note:** You may want to set the *encoding* within the `Out-File` cmdlet. E. g. `-Encoding utf8`

Comment: of course it is. I was trying to be too clever, and forgot all about `out-file` Cheers